# Create array with values of multiple select dropdown options

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this code:

```
var msg='';
var values = [];
$('.selectedoptionselect option:selected').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() > 0){
        var selected=$(this).val();
        values.push(selected +',');
    }else{
        msg='Please select option !';
    }
})
alert(values);
```

I have several dropdown menus and want to create a comma separate array with values of selected option. It makes array, but uncludes commas for each not selected option, but I want the array to be clear of empty commas and to have only values.. How to do so?

Thank you

Comment: may I ask what you downvote ?

Comment: are you asking for html or what? I realy dont understand what else you may need.. Html is standart select menus with class selectedoptionselect

Comment: Maybe create a demo with some sample HTML content that demonstrates the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your jQuery selector to

```
$('.selectedoptionselect')
```

The value of the select will be whatever option is selected.